Multiple dropdown with checkbox css
All I'm trying to do is toggle the 'toggle-content' class when the label is selected. At the moment with the following CSS nothing happens. I cannot use JQuery or any javascript. I cannot see what I've done wrong. Any ideas greatly appreciated.


/* The checkbox */
.hidden-checkbox {
   display: block;
}

/* The element to show/hide */
 .toggle-content {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    color: white;
    border: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
}

/* The label that controls the element */
.label-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Show the element when the checkbox is checked */
.hidden-checkbox:checked + .toggle-content {
    display: block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding-right: 10px
}

li {
    padding-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y)* -1);
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)* -.5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)* -.5);
    font-size: small;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}
<div>
    <label for="toggleVendors" class="label-toggle form-control">
        click here
    </label>
    <div type="checkbox" id="toggleVendors" class="hidden-checkbox" />
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="1" />one</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="2" />two</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="3" />three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>




Divs aren't inputs they can't have type: checkbox.

so in short, to make that code working, you need to make that div an input element and you have to change the .hidden-checkbox  css rule with display: none. There are surely plenty of Q/A here about that but couldn't find any

if I make the div an input then I have to select the checkbox specifically to toggle the content. clicking anywhere on the label has no effect.

no.. because you have a label using for targeting the checkbox. The point is that for accessibility reason, the click on the label will actually toggle the corresponding checkbox and will make the css rules conditions work accordingly. I told you one comment above the exact solution and your comment shows you didn't even try it

You have to use an actual checkbox and not a div. To combine a checkbox with a label, use the appropriate id on the checkbox so you can click on the text to toggle the checkbox


/* The checkbox */

.hidden-checkbox {
  display: none;
}


/* The element to show/hide */

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: white;
  border: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}


/* The label that controls the element */

.label-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Show the element when the checkbox is checked */

.hidden-checkbox:checked+.toggle-content {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-right: 10px
}

li {
  padding-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y)* -1);
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)* -.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)* -.5);
  font-size: small;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
<div>
  <label for="toggleVendors" class="label-toggle form-control">
        click here
    </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggleVendors" class="hidden-checkbox">
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="1" />one</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="2" />two</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="3" />three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>




I dont want the checkbox to show though. I want the user to only have to click on the label. If I have the above

you can achieve this with css, you initially specified the display for the hidden css with block. I set it now to none so that it's hidden.

interesting, I've litterally cut and pasted, but it does not work for me when I change the initial css for the checkbox to none

What a gotcha. This is a control that will be part of a master page. It wasn't working for me, because the master page had other css controls with the same class names taking precedence over this one which happened to have the same class name against an element. I've made sure they are unique and it now works.

sorry, just saw your comments now. Glad you could resolve your issues. but in such a case always make sure via the browsers dev tools that the correct CSS is applied. That also saved me some time from searching on the wrong end :)

Divs aren't inputs they can't have type: checkbox.
Swap it out for a proper input


/* The checkbox */

.hidden-checkbox {
  display: none;
}


/* The element to show/hide */

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: white;
  border: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}


/* The label that controls the element */

.label-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Show the element when the checkbox is checked */

.hidden-checkbox:checked+.toggle-content {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-right: 10px
}

li {
  padding-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y)* -1);
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)* -.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)* -.5);
  font-size: small;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
<div>
  <label for="toggleVendors" class="label-toggle form-control">
    click here
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggleVendors" class="hidden-checkbox">
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="1" />one</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="2" />two</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="3" />three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



